# Relationship Between Resistance and Magnet Strength for Electromagnets

Tags: current, resistance, electromagnetism, magnetics

I am working on a project using an electromagnet to vibrate the strings of a guitar at their resonant frequency. I have this working pretty well with an electromagnet I have on hand, I'm currently looking at other commercially available electromagnets to see which ones have the best characteristics for what I'm doing. By looking up the supplier of my original electromagnet I found the following product page, which shows that this model is available at a variety of resistance specs:

[image]

What I'd like to determine is what affect resistance has on the strength of the magnetism generated by a given voltage. Will a higher resistance lead to less magnetic strength? Is this relationship linear or are there other factors at play?

Ideally I'd like to source a magnet that gives me the strongest magnetism for the lowest current. I have a lot of experience with low voltage audio electronics but fairly new to working with electromagnets so all input is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Strength is rated in Ampere-turns while R affects temp rise from I^2R and Rth thermal resistance which reduces strength rapidly when hot. But for pulsing you may average the power.

Comment: "strongest magnetism for the lowest current" ... this usually means more windings, larger magnet -> more DC resistance. But understand that the magnetic materials vary significantly -- hysystesis and saturation. You may want something designed for "proportional" operation at audio frequencies, while most solenoids are designed for operation at one particular **DC** current level. Furthermore, as solenoids increase in power, more nonideal stuff is visible in impedance curve at audio frequencies (low kHz).

Comment: Get a signal generator and whatever you can use to make impedance measurements- scope, spectrum analyzer, network analyzer. Since you will be building or using an amp anyway, put that in the loop too, because result will vary as the magnet loads up.

Comment: Also if you need to achieve a particular magnetization amplitude at a particular frequency, and are working with a fixed voltage supply, then that may end up being the primary constraint

Answer (score 2):

With electromagnets there are *two* circuits. *Both* are equally important:

1. The electrical circuit, where the electromagnet coil is an inductor, and wires and other electronic devices are "conductors".
2. The magnetic circuit, where the electromagnet coil is a source of magnetic field, and the *armature*, as well as the empty space around the electromagnet, are the conductors.

   As it stands, the cylindrical armature acts as a resistor in the magnetic circuit, since the size of the poles is much larger than the diameter of the steel string.

To get strong interaction with small objects, at least one of the armature's poles needs to be scaled to match the small object in size.

So, the armature should look like a cut-off flat bladed screwdriver: circular diameter within the coil, narrowing to a flat tip to be placed underneath the string.

This way, you'll get much more pulling force out of the same coil - by concentrating magnetic flux to where it can do work and interact with the string.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the Series E-77-82 devices is rated for 1.25W (continuous). The power in a resistive device like these is given by

$$P = V^2/R$$

Where V is the operating voltage and R is the resistance.

The manufacturer offers basically the same electromagnet in different Voltage-Resistance configurations. At the low voltage end, there is thick wire, and hence few turns, and low resistance. At the high voltage end, there is thin wire, more turns, but higher resistance.

You suggested that you want to minimize current. You can do this at a price. The price is that, for the size of electro-magnet you are looking at, lower current comes with a higher required voltage. For a given pulling power, your electromagnet can only have lower current if it has more turns. But more turns means either smaller wire (and more resistance, and a higher voltage) or it means a larger sized device.

So, when deciding on which electromagnet to buy, choose the smallest series with the pulling force you need, and then choose the wire size/resistance/voltage based upon what voltage you have available to supply your electromagnet. If your voltage supply is too low for that magnet, you will not get the full pulling force for that magnet. If your voltage is too high for that magnet, it will overheat, and may burn out.